# Dynamically add code to div element in VB code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my .aspx page I have a div element with the id of mainGameBattle.

In the .vb code behind, I need to check a variable and if the condition is met, I need to dynamically load another .aspx page into the div with jQuery like this:

**.aspx**

```
<div id="mainGameBattle" runat="server" style="border: none;"></div>
```

**and code behind:**

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisBattle.Group) Then

     //add dynamic jQuery load event to div element....
     //<script type='text/javascript'>
         //$('#mainGameBattle').load('http://mysamedomain.org/spaceArena.aspx?battleID=" & thisBattle.ID & "');"
     //</script> 

End If
```

Is there a way of doing this in vb.net?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use something like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), New Guid().ToString(), "$('#mainGameBattle').load('http://example.com/spaceArena.aspx?battleID=" & thisBattle.ID & "');")
```

I may have used incorrect arguments though!